# What is the shortcut keys to scroll to the top or bottom of a PDF in Preview on macOS on a MacBook?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, pdf, macbook, preview, macos-mojave

What is the shortcut keys to scroll to the top or bottom of a PDF in Preview on macOS on a MacBook? I've tried everything I can think of. The answers I have found so far only refer to an extended keyboard. I just need the combo for a MacBook Pro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a MacBook keyboard, <kbd>fn</kbd>-<kbd>←</kbd> is equivalent to the extended keyboard "home" key, which in macOS means "beginning of document" (this confuses some people who come from Windows, where "Home" means "beginning of line).

<kbd>fn</kbd>-<kbd>→</kbd> is equivalent to the extended keyboard "End" key, which in macOS means "end of document" (not the Windows meaning of "end of line").

This works in almost every app, including Preview.

For sake of completeness, <kbd>fn</kbd> <kbd>↑</kbd>  is Page Up & <kbd>fn</kbd> <kbd>↓</kbd>  is Page Down

Comment: fn ↑ (page up) & fn ↓ (page down) work for me for PDFs in Preview, but the others to go to the begining or the end do not work for me (MacBook Pro Ventura)